# C Printing a char array in a struct that's stored in an array

Tags: arrays, c

Im having trouble trying to print out and store a char array. The char array "id" is stored in a struct which is then stored in an array of that struct. when i try to print the id i get a seg fault. any help would be great.
this is the struct

```
{
  const int NUM_MAX_FILES = 50;
  const int FILE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 256;
  typedef struct {
    char id[10]; //id
    char* addr; // The IP of the peer
    int file_count; // number of files
    char files[NUM_MAX_FILES][FILE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH]; // The files the peer broadcasts
} peer_struct;
```

Which is then stored into an array

```
peer_struct more_peers[50];
```

I have a nested loop that compares each peer and its files, to search for a matching file. Which works great, but when i try to get the id of the peer with the match i get a seg fault.
here is the code for if its a match.

```
if(strcmp(buf,more_peers[i].files[y]) == 0){
    printf("Found a match: ");
    printf("%s\n",more_peers[i].id); <-- this is where I get a seg fault.
    strcpy(val,more_peers[i].id);//store the value
}
```

and here is the code adding a new peer with a id

```
 recv(new_tcp_s, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
 buf[numbytes] = '\0';
 strcpy(tmp_peer.id,buf);
 printf("REG publish: peer id %s\n", tmp_peer.id ); <-- no seg fault here it 
 more_peers[ap_count] = tmp_peer;                   also prints the correct id
```

Comment: What is the value in `numbytes` and is it 10 or larger?

Comment: @BillLynch Yep its set to 100

Comment: The most likely thing is that `id` is being overwritten past the 10 bytes you allocated for it.  You should try using `strncpy` to bound the copy to max 10.  However, you'll also have to ensure `id` has a terminator at the last byte as well (strncpy doesn't guarantee a terminator).

Comment: Better still, run this in a debugger, let it puke, and start scoping variables in your stack frames. I have little doubt you've breached fixed addressable space *somewhere*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin they get initialized and deleted as peers connected and disconnect.

Comment: Where are each of the members in each struct in `peer_struct more_peers[50];` initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you write that `numbytes` is 100. This means that you are writing past the end of the `id` array, which is only 10 bytes long.

Good practice would involve replacing the strcpy with a function that takes the size of the destination array as an argument. For example:

```
snprintf(tmp_peer.id, 10, "%s", buf);
```